# Hooks for phone call state iOS

Tags: ios, core-telephony

I am looking for something similar to what is TrueCaller doing for android Don't know how it works in iOS, is it same way ?

Basically what is need is

1. A hook method to get call when call state changes.
2. And should be able to get the details in hook like phone number etc.
3. And make call to service with phone number for displaying name (unknown in case of no user found in our service) of who is calling in the screen.

Comment: i am also user of trueCaller and i did not get call number and details in my iPhone. like android so i dont think that will be possible in iOS same like androd.

Comment: is not possible in iOS

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik okay., how is the core-telephony works. ? i think there are hook methods available in core-telephony., will it provide phone number of receiving and making calls.? will it allow to call service to endpoint with the number?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik And no call recorders are possible?

Comment: now a days apple restricted this, in ios 6 and below we can do this,

Answer (score 1):

[Core Telephony](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/index.html) does not allow you to retrieve any other information that the connection state.

So you **CAN NOT** get the phone number that is calling you, this has to do with privacy.

The [`CTCall` Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CTCall) only has two properties:

- [`callID`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCall/callID) which is jus a unique id for this call, but not the phone number.
- [`callState`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCall/callState) which is the state of the call, which is `CTCallStateDialing`, `CTCallStateIncoming`, `CTCallStateConnected` or `CTCallStateDisconnected`.